# Pull multiple values from XML and return in one row

Tags: sql-server, xml, nodes

On SQL Server, I have an XML field on a record and it contains multiple nodes of a similar type, but with different IDs.
I want to pull a few IDs from that XML and return on one row.

Here is a simple example of the XML:

```
...
<Items>
  <Item>
     <ItemID>1</ItemID>
     <ItemValue>A</ItemValue>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ItemID>2</ItemID>
     <ItemValue>B</ItemValue>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

I want to output the values of the specific Items I'm searching for on one row.

Something like

```
select XML_Values 
from the_table
where conditions_met = true
```

I have used cross apply and can get just the nodes of the required values returning, but the output is all on separate rows.
Ideally the output Id like would be something along the lines of:

```
| Id=1  | Id=2 | (Column headers)
| A     | B    |
```

I'd be super grateful for any help.

Comment: It is not clear what you need. Please edit your post and clarify your **desired output**.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<Items>
    <Item>
        <ItemID>1</ItemID>
        <ItemValue>A</ItemValue>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ItemID>2</ItemID>
        <ItemValue>B</ItemValue>
    </Item>
</Items>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
    , c.value('(Item[1]/ItemValue/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS Item1
    , c.value('(Item[2]/ItemValue/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS Item2
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/Items') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------+-------+
| ID | Item1 | Item2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | A     | B     |
+----+-------+-------+
```